# Nonlinear differential equations with zero initial conditions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Suppose that we have $n$ differential equations of the form:

$\dot{x}_i(t) = f_i(g(x_1(t)), \ldots, g(x_n(t))) \qquad \qquad$   ($i=1,\ldots,n$).

where $f_i$ are linear functions, and $g$ is an antisymmetric nonlinear function, that is, $g(-x)=-g(x)$. Furthermore, $g(0) = 0$

Given $x_i(0) = 0$ and $\dot{x}_i(0)=0$ for all $i$, can we directly say that $x_i(t) = 0$ for all $i$ and $t\geq0$? If not, what are the further conditions required on $g$?

Comment: You must say something more about $g$ except that they are "non-linear" and odd.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on requirements on $g$. For example, consider the case $n=1$ and $x_1(t)=t^2$ for $t>0$, $x_1(t)=0$ for $t\leqslant 0$, $f_1(y)=y$. Then we should have $2t=g(t^2)$ for $t\geqslant 0$, such $g$ exists and may be odd as you ask for: $g(s)=2|s|^{1/2}\cdot {\rm sign}(s)$. But if $g_i$ are Lipschitz, you may apply the uniqueness theorem for Cauchy problem.

Comment: He has a requirement $g(-t)=-g(t)$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko indeed, fixed accordingly

Comment: Thanks Fedor. Assuming $g_i$ are Lipschitz, does it directly follow from the uniqueness theorem? I couldn't find an official statement for uniqueness theorem of $n$-dimensional systems containing the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @Jason yes, and actually it is enough to require $|g_i(x)|\leqslant C|x|$ for small enough $x$, then by Grönwall inequality you get $x\equiv 0$